# UEFI Win10 Installation: How do I separate the data and system into different partition?

Tags: windows, uefi, efi

I would like to separate system partition and data partition in my 1 TB SSD when installing Win10. It was possible in the MBR days, but now, it seemed that Win10 will wipe out the entire SSD during installation.
Is there a way to confine the Win10 installation in 1 partition?

EDIT:
in the MBR days, starting with fresh HDD (Say 1TB), I allocate 250GB to one partition, and install windows on it, assign drive letter C:. Once installed, i logged onto Windows to format the remaining 750GB and assign D:. I moved My Documents, Pictures, Downloads, Desktop to D:.

The next time system screwed up (like windows update) and I need to reinstall the system and confine the change to 1 partition,  i just work with C: and keep D: intact.

I cannot do that anymore in the UEFI implementation, any advice?

Comment: That is (now in my experience) an old line of thinking for days of cheap hard drives.  Good quality SSD drives do not benefit from extra partitions, backing up data is essential anyway to protect against ransomware, and Windows 10 is easy to install and activate on a new drive. I do not bother any more.

Comment: I think you got different answers to your question, all valid, from my perspective. You can either do it during install (but you do have to allocate disk space for your System partition manually), or shrink your C drive to free as much empty space you need to store your data AFTER you've finished installing and updating Windows. Disk Management will let you do that, with one caveat: during install, files and file fragments will be scattered all over your (sole) System partition, which could make shrinking it problematic. I'd go with partitioning during install, not after, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible during the installation of Windows.

Ensure to select the installation type of
"Custom: Install Windows only (advanced)"
and that the entire drive is marked as "Unallocated Space"
(delete partitions if not).

Select the Unallocated Space and click the "New" button.
You can now set the size of the system partition
(I suggest at least 100 GB).

Install Windows in the new partition. Afterword, use Disk Management to
allocate the unallocated part of the disk.

For more info with screenshots see
[How To Create Custom Partition To Install Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/create-custom-partition-install-windows-10/).

Comment: You do not have to create a partition first. Just select the unallocated space, and windows will create the 4 partitions it wants.

Comment: So, delete the old windows install partition, select the unallocated space, and press install.

Comment: @LPChip: The poster would like to separate system & data, so needs manual control of the system partition's size. He shouldn't give everything to the system partition.

Comment: They say they already have an existing installation with separate data partition. So if they only delete the partition windows is installed on, then select that unallocated space to install windows on, windows will, if there is not already a recovery partition, create those partitions for you.

Comment: @LPChip: I read the post differently, but no matter.